# How to get today's date automatically in post title in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am currently using WordPress and I have seen this in many sites' post title while searching in Google. Example, audi q7 price in UK on (today's date)   example [site](http://www.priceinindian.net/highscreen-spark-2). Somewhere I read that I have to add code in `functions.php`.  but can't out that source.

```
$output .= '<label style="color:#888888;font-size:11px;padding-top:2px;font-style:italic;"> (' . $related_post->post_date . ') </label>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a related post plugin? If so, you should definitely include that info in your question.

I think [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-date-beside-post-title-1) or [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-related-post) may provide the answer you need.

And note, if you are editing the plugin code, not the functions.php file -- updating the plugin will probably overwrite your changes.

AFTER MORE INFO FROM SO ---------

To get today's date -- at least the date set in the server hosting the website -- you enter:

```
<?php
echo date("d F Y");
?>
```

You need to enter this code into your template. If you're already within a block of PHP, then you just enter

```
echo date("d F Y");
```

There are [other options](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) for the date() function, but this one outputs the date as

```
20 December 2015
```

Comment: Where did you get the code you posted? Do you want to post today's date like the link you provided? Or do you want to display the date of the post? What do you mean when you write "...but can't out that source"?

Comment: i had to add the code because i was unable to add the the question here.........   yes i want to post today's date like the link i provided....  as you can see in the link that author has only written highscreen spark 2 but in title it is showing highscreen spark 2 price in india (today's date).... i also want the same thing.. and the date  should be updated daily

Comment: See my revised answer, now that I know what the SO wanted.

Comment: well i am using wordpress where to add it

Comment: Add it where ever you want it to appear. Has to be in a template, tho.